# Flask and socket.io broadcast

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, flask

I want to use SocketIO to broadcast messages when a certain event on the server happens, right now I use this code

http://pastebin.com/i2jNf1w5

and I call `gevent.spawn(loop_send_queued_messages, server)` when launching my server

when a client sends data to '/emit' everything works fine:

- I see the `broadcasting` message from `broadcast`
- I see the `broadcast_msg` message from `broadcast_msg`

However, if in another part of the server I import the `broadcast` function and I use it from some endpoint (for instance after a user sent a file), I only see the first `broadcasting` message from the call to `broadcast`, but it seems that the message is not properly added to the queue because `broadcast_msg` is never called

Could someone tell me the best way to user SocketIO in Flask to do broadcasting from any location in my server code?

[EDIT] Taking into account the comment below, I have this

```
broadcasting newDatasetAvailable features 4363892432 scripts.socket_routes
127.0.0.1 - - [2013-12-11 15:56:07] "POST /datastore/features HTTP/1.1" 200 115 0.003130
broadcasting msg refreshData 4363648208 socket_routes
127.0.0.1 - - [2013-12-11 15:56:07] "POST /emit HTTP/1.1" 200 115 0.000540
broadcast_msg msg (u'refreshData',)
```

so one is `scripts.socket_routes`, the other is `socket_routes`

the `/emit` endpoint is defined in the same file as the `websocket_queue`, and a `POST` to `/datastore` uses the `broadcast` method from another file, and imports it like that:

```
from scripts.socket_routes import broadcast
```

where the structure is:

```
scripts/
    __init__.py
    socket_routes.py # where websocket_queue and broadcast are defined
    dataset_routes.py # where broadcast is imported
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a subtle issue with how you are importing the module. I.e. you may have the module loaded twice under two different module names and not realize it.

Modify the print in broadcast() like this:

```
print "broadcasting", name, data, id(websocket_queue), __name__
```

Make sure that the same id and module name displays when called from the server code as when called when the client sends data.

If the information doesn't match, then this is the likely problem. It is usually caused by relative imports (which are evil). Switch to [absolute imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) everywhere and that may fix it.

When using Python 2.6 or earlier, I add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the top of every module in order to prevent these kinds of problems.

Comment: Indeed the two queues are not the same, but I think I'm only using absolute imports (`import module.submodule` and not `import .submodule`), how can I change my imports or make sure the object is shared? I thought `import` in Python would not reimport a file if it was already imported no?

Comment: What module names were printed? What is the layout of your code relative to this module and where you are importing it? What do your import statements look like?

Comment: by replacing `from scripts.socket_routes import broadcast` by `from socket_routes import broadcast` it works but I'm wondering what is the proper way to do the import, because if I start using directly the file name everywhere it might collide with system packages, no?

Comment: Correct, you want to stick with absolute imports in order to avoid colliding with system packages. Where is the import statement that leads to the gevent.spawn call? That's the one importing the module relatively.

Comment: I got it working by refactoring my package, I put all the server related code in `scripts/server` and I have a `scripts/server.py` code that does an `import server` to launch my server, and now the files in `scripts/server/...` can use `import server.socket_routes`

Comment: That's better but seems to still rely on relative imports (because scripts is the top of your code right?). I.e., use `import scripts.server` and `import scripts.server.socket_routes`. In other words, any time you do an import, always specify it from the top of your code base.